# best practice to pass two required parameters in REST GET request

Tags: api, api-design

I'm designing an API and I've two required parameters that are mandatory for this action

I've two options to pass them

1)
/servers/server_id/exte/device_id/agents/agent_id/live_monitoring

Disadvantage: toooooo long

2)
/servers/server_id/live_monitoring?device_id=23&agent_id=767

Disadvantage: these parameters shouldn't be query parameters because they are required not optional

Which approach should I go with?

Answer (score 2):

You should decide

- If this parameters define child resources then you should use
  /parent/:id/child/:child_id url
- If this parameters used only for filtering data then you should use ?param_1=parm_1_value

About long url
If you don't need to check access rights or something else belong to parent resource you can use either

```
/server/{:server_id|/exte/{:device_id}/agent/{:agent_id}/live_monitoring
```

or

```
/agent/{:agent_id}/live_monitoring
```

But this will be two different resources

Answer (score 0):

You're still better to go with the query parameters (it's the RESTful approach), but handle them on the endpoint side to return an error if they're not provided.

For instance, in php, you'd do:

```
if (!isset($_GET['device_id']))
    echo json_encode(array("error"=>"You need to provide device_id"));
if (!isset($_GET['agent_id']))
    echo json_encode(array("error"=>"You need to provide agent_id"));
```